# Don't know how to handle multiple users at once on python3 flask website

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, flask

I've recently created a website with a login system but it only works if only one user is on the website at the time. For example, if I were to login and someone else were to access my website, they would automatically be logged into my account. How am i meant to make each user session seperate?

```
logged = False
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def home():
    global logged
    if request.method == 'POST':
        logged = False
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    else:
        if not logged:
            return render_template('home.html')
        elif logged:
            return render_template('logged.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    global logged, username
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        con = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
        c = con.cursor()
        user = False

        if c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", [username]):
            for row in c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", [username]):
                user = row

        if user:
            if user[1] == password:
                logged = True
            con.commit()
            con.close()
            if logged:
                return redirect(url_for('home'))
            else:
                return render_template('loginerror.html')
        else:
            return render_template('loginerror.html')
    else:
        return render_template('login.html')
```

On the homepage, there is a login button and when a user logs in, it redirects them to the home page and sets logged to True. However this affects every user on the website and logs all of them into the same account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what you're doing. It's a subtle mistake and easy to overlook. You are setting the values of "logged" and "username" when a user logs in. These values are stored in memory on the server. Therefore when anyone else accesses your website, they are logged in to the same account.

I'm not sure if you have read about HTTP requests being stateless. Stateless means that for any request recevied by the server, the server does not remember anything from a previous request. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol) has a good article on this.

What you want to do is use cookies or some sort of session mechanism to establish authentication between users and the server. Check out this [tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins) for more info on how to do this with Flask.